# phrasing a wishes?

Tags: phrase-request

I do not know the best way to wish (for a reply) for a new year, for healthy life and for successes.

> We also wish this New Year brings you and your family every success
>   and healthiness.

Would this be ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We also wish this New Year brings you and your family every success and healthiness.

That phrasing is grammatically and semantically acceptable, but not perfectly natural.  I'd expect to hear  “good health” rather than  “healthiness” and “hope” instead of “wish” in the above.   *[Wish](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wish#Verb)* is not wrong there, but I think more typically is followed by *you*.  For example,

> We wish you and your family every success and the best of health in this New Year.